# shortcode in snippet plugin not work

Tags: shortcode

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wpb_new_product_tab' );
function wpb_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    // Add the new tab
    $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
        'title'       => __( 'Size Chart', 'text-domain' ),
        'priority'    => 50,
        'callback'    => 'wpb_new_product_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}

function wpb_new_product_tab_content() {
    // The new tab content
    echo 'Size Chart';
    echo '[table id=2 responsive=collapse responsive_breakpoint="phone" /]
" /.';          
}
```

Comment: what is the snippet plugin you're referring to? If it doesn't do what you want it to do, what does it do instead? Where is this code located? Shortcodes need to return their output, not `echo` it